# I want to rename files then copy them to one folder

Tags: directory, copy

I have hundreds of files called "report.json" inside folders

each folder contains files and subfolders

for example, I have a folder called **1** and inside this folder, I have another other files and folders and there is a file called "report.json" I need to copy this file to another folder and rename this file as 1_report.json and do that in all folders.

I want a script to go inside these folders and rename and copy the file report.json (FolderName_report.json)

so I will have in my new folder
1_report.json
2_report.json
3_report.json etc (1,2,3 are the folders names )

Answer (score 0):

Read `man find xargs grep cut bash` and do something like **UNTESTED**:

```
# In $HOME/bin/copy_report: 

#!/bin/bash
# copy "dir1/dir2/report.json" to $outputdir/dir1_report.json
debug=0
if [[ "$1" = "--debug" ]]; then
  debug=1
  shift
fi
# Adjust as needed 
outputdir="$HOME/output_dir"

[[ -d "$outputdir" ]] || mkdir --mode=0750 "$outputdir"

while [[ $# -gt 0 ]] ; do
  fromfile="$1"
  shift
  field_one="$(echo "$fromfile" | cut -d/ -f1)"
  field_onetwo="$(echo "$fromfile" | cut -d/ -f1,2 | tr '/' '_' )"
  tofile="$outputdir/${field_one}_report.json"
  if [[ $debug -ne 0 ]] ; then
    echo "cp \"$fromfile\"  \"$tofile\""
  else
    cp "$fromfile"  "$tofile"
fi
done
```

Then,

```
find . -type f -name 'report.json' -print0 |  \
  xargs -0  -r $HOME/bin/copy_report --debug
```

Remove the "`--debug`" in the last line when you are satisfied.